# Edit hijacking: Do we care?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently editted a question, and will admit it was minor in the sense that I helped to format some code and text, as well as clarifying the question in general.

I had come back to the question not long after, to see that not only has the original asker of the question rejected my edit, but actually copied it character for character and used it as his own edit.

Being only marginally upset about the +2 reputation I missed out on, I wondered if this is something that others in the community had an opinion on at all?

Should there be any system in place to detect/report this kind of action? How would this even work? If so, what would the repercussions be for the 'edit hijacker'?

Comment: Thats not okay. can we have a link?

Comment: Unless you notice a weird pattern of such thing, don't bother. @Mag Come on, let's not have the meta effect again.

Comment: It's probably "improve edit".

Comment: It might not have been intentional - perhaps the OP isn't familiar with the editing system and somehow thought he had to copy + paste.

Comment: Meh.  It's hard to tell if it was malicious or just a weird coincidence/edit conflict.  And as long as the post is still in a decent state, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Rizier123, Improve edit would have given the editor his +2 rep, which didn't happen here.

Comment: @Kyll I want to see if it actually happened that way or if it was a weird conflict type thing or a misplaced reject & edit.

Comment: ["This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12710690) You edited at the same time.

Comment: Nothing bad happened here.  You got caught in a conflict of edits.  This does not count against you as far as edit bans go.

Comment: The subsequent edits seem to be my edits by the original asker? Unless I'm misunderstanding what caused the conflict.

Comment: @JonasCz When improving an edit (which, granted, wasn't the case here) you can *either* approve or reject the initial edit, so it wouldn't necessarily have been approved.

Comment: Your edit was pending when the OP submitted their edit. Since the OP has final say on the edit, the system (aka Community) rejects the pending suggested edit. See also [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37859316/timeline) the OP's edit was submitted ~30 seconds after your suggestion went into the queue.

Comment: For future reference: How do I check if an edit has been approved/rejected? I didn't know such a view existed.

Comment: @HopefulLlama under [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1397285/hopeful-llama?tab=activity) page you see a history of all of your suggested edits, and it indicates wether they're rejected or approved. If you click on the "approved edit" or "rejected edit" or "pending edit" links in there it'll take you to the review queue item.

Comment: @Servy, Choosing "Reject and edit" gives you the original version of the post to edit, so the editor would still have to copy and paste the edit somehow, which seems unlikely. But yes, you're right.

Comment: The post timeline is also helpful for seeing when things happened. The link is `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/####/timeline` where `####` is the post id number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as I thought. Your edit wasn't rejected because someone voted to reject it; it was [rejected because it conflicted with a subsequent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12710690) which was made by the OP. What likely happened was that OP was mid-edit and saw your suggestion, and copied it into his edit window and hit submit, thinking that would make it go through, which caused your edit to be auto rejected.

Worth noting: A rejected edit for this reason does not count against you in any way.